# No internet access whith VPN and Android 12

Tags: vpn, android-12

In my Xiaomi redmi note 10 pro I have two VNP clients: Cisco AnyConnect and OpenVPN.

They were both working fine and I had access to internet even with active VPN connection.

After the upgrade from Android 11 to Android 12, I have no internet access when a VPN connection is open.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

There have been some reported cases same as yours.

These methods often got rid of the glitch:

1. Clear VPN App Storage and Cache
2. Disable Smart Switch Between WiFi and Mobile Data
3. Update the VPN App
4. Reset Network Settings
5. Reinstall the VPN App

---

If all of the fore-mentioned methods fail follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diFi8BJYr3c) to grant app ops the ADB permission and then manually grant the VPN permission to the app.

As [Drew_pew_pew_pew](https://www.reddit.com/user/Drew_pew_pew_pew/) mentions:

> I have the same phone and same crap. I use app ops and shizuku to manually grant vpn apps permission. https://youtu.be/diFi8BJYr3c . Had problems with the wireless method at first. But once you paired and press start in shizuku, I had to go back in dev settings and disable/enable wireless debugging again.

[Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/motorola/comments/zo38xu/comment/j0l1z7f/)